# Any limitations creating processes under Azure Web Sites (specifically Web Jobs)?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

Are there any limitations on creating separate processes from an Azure Web Site (specifically, from a continuous Web Job)? I have an executable that often (about %20 of the time) stalls and eventually fails with exit code -1073741819 (access denied? or access violation?), but only when run as a separate process. If this work is retried later, it eventually succeeds (usually on the first retry).

When instead I call this logic directly via a .NET method call (so within the same process and app domain), the code succeeds 100% of the time. The same code also always succeeds when run locally, even when it creates a separate process.

Is there anything going on at the Azure Web Sites/Web Jobs level that I should be aware of, such as using Windows job objects or other security mechanisms to limit the creation or runtime of spawned processes? If not, any suggestions on how to diagnose further what might be going wrong? (I believe remote desktop to a web site isn't possible; anything else that would help "see" what's failing, such as whether there's a WER dialog appearing?)

In case it matters, the logic (in both cases) includes P/Invoking custom native code, and the web site I'm using is Always On, x64, Basic pricing tier.

Comment: Try following [these steps](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Isolating-WebJobs-and-Deployment-script-issues) to help isolate/diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

@David Ebbo, thanks for the suggestion. I used it to help isolate, and I ultimately found this was non-determinism in the code made more likely in the Azure Web Sites environment but not 100% restricted to that context.